# How to fix "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" through a firewall

Tags: python

I am writing a basic Python program with the end goal of scraping data from websites for data processing/streamlining. It works fine when I'm not connected to the company network, however when I try when I'm connected to the company network it does not work.

I have connected to an "alternative" network at work, with fewer restrictions, and it works fine. However this is not a long term solution as connection to this network means I do not have access to my files and email, which I need.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.google.com')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: So your question is how to violate your company's firewall?

Comment: You question has nothing to do with python. Network restrictions exist for a reason. To remove a restriction (even partially) you usually need to file a request with your network admin explaining your need to access a certain network resource

Comment: presumably you can browse the web at work?  if so, you probably need to tell Python to use the same proxy servers your web browser is using

Comment: I am able to put in a request from IT, what is it that is being blocked though? Is it python itself?

Answer (score 0):

as others said, if you are able to load google in your browser while you are connected to company network then its most likely because your company uses proxy.
Requests module supports proxy so you can use obe.

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate please? What do you mean by obe?